# how replace exact word using sed which starts with special character "

Tags: replace

I need to replace a word   "/hotel  to "/Tay

I used various delimiters like ? $ but I couldn't get it

Comment: Do you need to use `sed`? Parameter expansion can do this: `FOO='abc"/hoteldef'; echo ${FOO/"\/hotel/"\/Tay}`

Comment: Since the characters `"/` exist in both 'words', why not only change `hotel` to `Tay` using `FOO='abc"\hoteldef'; echo ${FOO/hotel/Tay}`?

Comment: If any of the existing answers solves your problem, please consider accepting it via the checkmark. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

People usually use forward slash `/` as the sed delimiter, but you can use any character you want; for example, `!`. Ideally, use a delimiter that doesn't appear in your search or replacement text, otherwise you'd need to quote it.

```
$ echo '"/hotel' | sed s!^"/hotel!"/Tay!
"/Tay
```

I quoted:

> "hotel

with single-quotes to keep the shell from getting confused about the lone double-quote mark. Here's an unquoted version (that thus has to escape the double-quote marks from the shell):

```
$ echo \"/hotel | sed s!^"/hotel!"/Tay!
```

Edited to include the `^` "beginning of line" character to enforce the match at the beginning of the line. Example of a non-match:

```
$ echo foo\"/hotel | sed s!^"/hotel!"/Tay!
foo"/hotel
```

Comment: It should be enough using sed "s/\"\/hotel/\"\/Tay/g"

Comment: indeed that works; it gets into the ["leaning toothpick"](http://www.wall.org/~larry/chunking) problem, though, which is why I suggested changing the delimiter.

Answer (score -1):

One way to do this is to escape the **/** and **"** with a "\"

> echo '"/hotel' | sed 's/\"/hotel/Tay/g'